# How to draw line on panel with background image in C#

Tags: c#

I have a double buffered panel which has a background image. Now when I draw line on panel its good but when I move that line in panel area it takes a snapshot or background with it where it was first located. I thought double buffered panel will solve this but its not working and I also try to add refresh panel code in mouse down event but then line constantly flickers so please guys help me.

```
 public void LineMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var l = (Line)sender;

    if (GetDistance(e.X, e.Y, l.StartPoint.X, l.StartPoint.Y) < 30 ||
        GetDistance(e.X, e.Y, l.EndPoint.X, l.EndPoint.Y) < 30)
    {
        _rotating = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _dragging = true;
       panel5.Refresh();
    }

    _clickX = e.X;
    _clickY = e.Y;

    panel5.Refresh();
    _clickCoords = new Point(l.Left + e.X, l.Top + e.Y);

    UpdateCircle(l);
    UpdateMiddle(l);
}

public void LineMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _rotating = false;
    _dragging = false;
    panel5.Refresh();
}

public void LineMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var l = (Line)sender;
    if (_rotating)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - lastRotate).TotalMilliseconds > 60)
        {
            try
            {
                var angle = GetAngle(l.Left + e.X, l.Top + e.Y, _centerX, 0, _centerX, _centerY);

                var newStartPoint = new Point(
                    (int)Math.Round(_middleX + _radius * Math.Sin(angle)),
                    (int)Math.Round(_middleY + _radius * Math.Cos(angle))
                );

                var newEndPoint = new Point(2 * _middleX - newStartPoint.X, 2 * _middleY - newStartPoint.Y);

                l.SetPoints(newStartPoint, newEndPoint);

                UpdateMiddle(l);

                lastRotate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            catch
            {
                //ignored
            }
        }
    }
    else if (_dragging)
    {
        l.Left = l.Left + e.X - _clickX;
        l.Top = l.Top + e.Y - _clickY;
    }
}
```

[Here what it looks like when I move line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xCU0.png)

```
 public class DoubleBufferPanel : Panel
{


    public DoubleBufferPanel()
    {

        // Set the value of the double-buffering style bits to true.
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;



        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
         ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw , true);


        this.UpdateStyles();


    }


}
```

Comment: Please take a look at image I attached it will give you clear idea what I meant to say.. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'moving the background'`Also: Just how do you draw the Line?? And what are the Updatexxx call doing??? Is the Background image zoomed or stretched? Finally: Are you talking about the red lines or the greyish half circle?

Comment: The panel appears to have some kind of transparency effect, seems like its OnPaintBackground() method does not run..  None of the code you posted has anything to do with the problem.  Random guess: painting in Panel requires disabling a paint optimization that is only appropriate for container controls.  Set the ResizeRedraw property to *true* in the constructor.   Next random guess: avoid WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.  Next random guess: call Invalidate() in an override for OnLocationChanged().  Don't force us to randomly guess.

Comment: You should be using `Invalidate()` to signal redraw, not calling `Refresh()`. If you've set double-buffering correctly, it should solve flickering for that control, but there are some "gotchas" in Winforms wrt double-buffering. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient info and code, but I was not sure that this is problem of that lines or panel. So I have added code of dubblebuffered panel which I used. 1.  Now I have added ResizeRedraw property and set it to true but still problem persists 2. I have used panel5.Invalidate in mousemove event but its not working. So please  comment here if you any other suggestions and also if you need any other piece of code please comment. And also flickering is not problem, problem is what I attached in image. Please see that you will get more idea. Thanks